# Events of an image in HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working with a banner, which have some buttons that I control with the events `onmouseover()` and `onmouseout()` with the  tag as follow:

```
<img src="image_1.png" 
     onmouseover="this.src='image_2.png'"
     onmouseout="this.src='image_1.png'" />
```

This is working perfectly, but I want to know if there is some kind of event of holding an image when it has been clicked, in order to know on which zone I am working on.

I hope I made myself clear.

Supose I have SECTION 1, SECTION 2, SECTION 3. So, when I select SECTION 1, the image SECTION 1, appears to be selected the hole time I am working on that SECTION. If I change to SECTION 2, only the image of SECTION 2 appears to be selected, and so on!

Comment: `<img src="image_1.png" onclick="this.src='image_3.png';" />`. Not that I'm suggesting inline handlers...

Comment: i have tried onclick adding that event on my <img> tag but it does not appear as pressed!!

Comment: What do you want to know/do about/to the image? The location of the cursor? The `src`, `height`, `width`..? What do you mean by 'zone [you're] working on'?

Comment: sorry for my english. What I meant was the SECTION I am working on. I have three sections, the images make a kind of MENU

Comment: Can you post the actual mark-up you're using? Maybe post a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try jquery hover to keep the current actions.

[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/N3ZDL/):

```
<img src="image_1.png" />

<script>
$('img').hover(
 function(){
   $(this).attr('src','image_2.png');
 },
 function(){
   $(this).attr('src','image_1.png');
 },
);
</script>
```

Maybe, other option could be a css :hover and :active filters, using background propertie.
[See this css example](http://jsfiddle.net/N3ZDL/2/)

```
.Myimg{
 display:block;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    background-image:url('img1.jpg');
}

.Myimg:hover{
   background-image:url('img2.jpg');
}
```

Comment: OP is asking about the click event!

Comment: ***Why..?*** What does jQuery offer to solve his problem? The `hover()` method merely replicates his current use-case.

Comment: @David: I think jquery is better than js inline

Comment: @MartinBorthiry, native JavaScript has its own abilities to assign `onmouseover`/`onmouseout` events without using jQuery. I, personally, tend to use jQuery where appropriate, but in this question it wasn't asked for, it wasn't tagged, and `hover()` doesn't solve, or address, the problem that was posted.

Answer (score 1):

what about the `onclick` event?

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using the CSS :hover psuedoselector rather than binding handlers to the onmouseover and onmouseout events.

See a decent tutorial [here](http://www.zoomcities.com/forum/showthread.php?tid=6856).

Comment: Could you perhaps summarise the important bits of that tutorial here?

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful: http://jsfiddle.net/BGurung/UDceq/

I created a flag that tells whether the image was clicked or not. On mouse out, if the image was clicked, sets the flag to false and returns, other was just changes the source of image.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want onmousedown & onmouseup but it really depends on what your doing.

Check out the specs for more info:

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/

Comment: Yes, I mean something like onmousedown or onmouseup but I didnt know them

Comment: supose I have three sections in the site....SECTION 1, SECTION 2,SECTION 3 and each section has its own image, what I need is that when I select the SECTION 1, it appears to be the one selected the hole time I work in that section!

Comment: Not quite sure what you really after, but found the sounds of it you want to be able to apply something to a selection on click. Below is an example of this using the latest jQuery

http://jsfiddle.net/Phunky/p2uVB/